# WebAPI 2 ValidateModelAttribute not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, custom-action-filter

I have a custom `ValidateModelAttribute` but it's not firing for some reason

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace blank.Utilities.CustomAttributes
{
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Post call

```
[ValidateModelAttribute]
[HttpPost]
[Route("update")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(ActivityPctCompleteDto actDto) {
    _activityService.UpdatePctComplete(actDto);
    return Ok();
}
```

I have added `fromBody` and `fromUri` in the post but it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Here is my Dto

```
public class ActivityPctCompleteDto
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ActivityID is an invalid Guid value.")]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PctComplete is an invalid Decimal(5,4) value.")]
    public decimal? PctComplete { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and action filter works fine for me. To diagnose your problem check the following:

1. Are you using `ActionFilterAttribute` from `System.Web.Http.Filters` namespace? There is a common confustion with filters from `System.Web.Mvc`.
2. What HTTP result do you get for you request? May be it fails on some earlier stage in ASP.NET pipeline, like routing or authentication?
3. Are you sure that exactly this `Post()` method processes the request? Try setting breakpoint and check whether it hits.

Comment: 1. Yes, I have and I have updated my portion of the code in my question. 2. 200 OK. 3. Yes the values are null if not the correct type. I have to be missing something simple here.

Comment: I have also registered it in the filterconfig.cs

Comment: Strange, your action filter works fine for me and from provided snippets it's unclear what is the root cause of your problem. Could you publish whole solution on github or upload archive with it on some publich storage?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Apparently after reinstalling `system.net.http` everything started working again.